# update second select box options based on the first select box options

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have the below select boxes.

```
<select id="directorate">
  <option value="1|CEO">CEO</option>
  <option value="2|Community">Community</option>
  <option value="3|Media">Media</option>
  <option value="4|Development">Development</option>
  <option value="5|Social">Social</option>
</select>

<select id="department">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="1">C</option>
  <option value="2">D</option>
  <option value="3">E</option>
  <option value="3">F</option>
  <option value="3">G</option>
</select>
```

When I select CEO as the directorate, it should only show A and B from the department list. Below is my sample jquery code. For some reason it doesn't work and if anyone can direct me in the correct path that would be great!

```
$('#directorate').change(function() {
var rawValue = $(this).val().split('|');
    $('#department option').each(function () {
        var NewValue = $(this).val().split('|');
        if (rawValue[0] !== newValue[0]) {
            $(this).remove();  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to use a debugger to find out what is happend

Comment: `NewValue != newValue`, check for errors in console.

Comment: I added a demo for you here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32306383/4323504

Comment: I have tried this with IE browser and doesn't seem to work. What could be the issue?

Comment: @luthando-loot I have also created a JSFiddle for this - http://jsfiddle.net/vkgvcztw/4/

Comment: @user2574948 hide/show have issues in IE, i'm working on an alternative solution, please give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw many mistakes in your solution, one of them was that you are using `newValue` in your if statement but you declared `NewValue` instead.Here is a working solution

```js
$('#directorate').change(function() {
  $('#department').val( '' );
var rawValue = $(this).val().split('|');
    $('#department option').each(function () {
        var newValue = $(this).val();
        if (rawValue[0] != newValue[0] && rawValue[0] != "") {
            $(this).hide();  
        }
      else{$(this).show(); }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="directorate">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="1|CEO">CEO</option>
  <option value="2|Community">Community</option>
  <option value="3|Media">Media</option>
  <option value="4|Development">Development</option>
  <option value="5|Social">Social</option>
</select>

<select id="department">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="1">C</option>
  <option value="2">D</option>
  <option value="3">E</option>
  <option value="3">F</option>
  <option value="3">G</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

> I have noticed that jquery's `hide/show` doesn't really work well with IE.

**Here is an alternative solution**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var options = $('#department').children().clone();
  
    $('#directorate').change(function() {
      $('#department').children().remove();
    var rawValue = $(this).val().split('|');
     options.each(function () {
            var newValue = this.value;
            if (rawValue[0] == newValue[0] || rawValue[0] =="") {
                $('#department').append(this);
             }
        });
      $('#department').val('');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="directorate">
     <option value="">---</option>
      <option value="1|CEO">CEO</option>
      <option value="2|Community">Community</option>
      <option value="3|Media">Media</option>
      <option value="4|Development">Development</option>
      <option value="5|Social">Social</option>
</select>

<select id="department">
      <option value="">---</option>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="1">B</option>
      <option value="1">C</option>
      <option value="2">D</option>
      <option value="3">E</option>
      <option value="3">F</option>
      <option value="3">G</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @user2574948 I am glad i could help

Comment: I have tried this with IE browser and doesn't seem to work. What could be the issue?

Comment: @user2574948 okay i will check it now and get back to you

Comment: It works @luthando-loot :) May I ask you why you have inserted rawValue[0] =="" inside the IF tag? Do we need this as the departments are loaded by default on page load?

Comment: @user2574948 If you take a look at my html you will notice i added a default option `---` with a blank value, I want to display all the options if that value is selected on the 1st select

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you are removing the not required options and hence when you change directorate option it does not find the required option in next select box. instead you can show /hide options, see below code

```
$('#directorate').change(function() {
var rawValue = $(this).val().split('|');
    //hide all options by default
    $('#department option').hide();
    $('#department').find('option[value="' + rawValue[0] + '"]').hide();
});
```